# Inside lambda function - Blazing text algorithm invoke endpoint doesn't support the input content type

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nlp, amazon-sagemaker

Im working on sentence classification using in-build  blazing text algorithm, while invoking endpoint inside lambda function it throughs the content type mismatching error.

-- For blazing text it support only application/jsonlines or application/json but while invoking , it throughs the error like , it accepts only byte or bytearray

```
input format . application/json
event={
  "features": [
    "sensor_subtype Thermostats Thermal Switches product_features Hermetically sealed n Tight tolerances n Tight differentials n Logic level contacts n applications Computers n Medical electronics n Power supplies n Industrial controls n Test equipment n Infotech n description Technical Specifications technical_specs CloseTolerance 2 8 C 5 F DielectricStrength MIL STD 202 Method 301 1250 Vac 60 Hz Terminal to Case ContactResistance MIL STD"
  ]
}
```

and also i tried application/jsonlines

My code looks like this>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
def transform_data(data):
    try:
        features = data.copy()

        return features

    except Exception as err:
        print('Error when transforming: {0},{1}'.format(data,err))
        raise Exception('Error when transforming: {0},{1}'.format(data,err))


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:    
        print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

        request = json.loads(json.dumps(event))

        transformed_data = str(transform_data(request['features'])) #for instance in request['features'])
        print(ENDPOINT_NAME, "------->>>>")
        payload=transformed_data
        result = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME, 
                              Body=(payload.encode('utf-8')),
                              ContentType='application/json')
        return result
```

```
  "statusCode": 400,
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "body": "Call Failed An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (406) from model with message \"Invalid payload format\".
_______________LOGS__________________________________

11:35:22
[08/18/2019 11:35:22 ERROR 140074862942016] Customer Error: Unable to decode payload: Incorrect data format. (caused by ValueError)

11:35:22
Caused by: No JSON object could be decoded

11:35:22
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/amazon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blazingtext/serve.py", line 317, in invocations data = json.loads(payload.decode("utf-8")) File "/opt/amazon/python2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/opt/amazon/python2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode obj, end = self.

11:35:22
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I need to predict the sentence in realtime using invoke_endpoint option but it shows invalid payload format

I tried with byte format and apllication/jsonlines format.

Comment: Your message Body is a string, but it needs to be a JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem when trying to predict on text classification with a BlazingText container. What worked for me was simply changing the key in the payload while keeping the ContentType as application/json:

```
sentence = "I'm selling my PS4, practically brand new"

payload = {"instances": [sentence]}

response = client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName="text_classification",
        Body=json.dumps(payload),
        ContentType='application/json'
        
    )
```

After playing around a little with the payload it seems that blazing text models only accept payloads as a dictionary with "instances" as its key and a list containing your data you want to predict on as its value.

To get to your predictions simply :

```
print("ResponseMetadata:", response["ResponseMetadata"])
print()
print("Body:", response['Body'].read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the following in invoke end point

```
Body=json.dumps(payload.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to get the response in Json format you need to change :

```
print("Body:", response['Body'].read())
```

TO

```
print("Body:", response['Body'].read().decode())
```